# TypeScript intersection types and readonly properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a piece of code in TypeScript that boils down to this pattern:

```
function test(x: {theFlag: boolean} & {readonly theFlag: boolean} ){
    x.theFlag = true;
}
```

But I get the following error on this line `x.theFlag = true;`

> [ts] Cannot assign to 'theFlag' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

I don't know why TypeScript is giving me an error on this. I think logically this should be allowed.

Is there a good workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I'm using TypeScript version 2.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler is playing it safe, since the property is readonly in one of the constituent types, it is readonly in the intersection.

In 2.8 you can easily create a type that removed the `readonly` from any property:

```
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P]};
function test(x: Mutable<{theFlag: boolean} & {readonly theFlag: boolean}> ){
  x.theFlag = true;
}
```

In 2.7 and below, I think the following definition of `Mutable` should do the trick, I don't use any 2.8 syntax, but I don't have an old version to test:

```
type MutableHelper<T, TNames extends string> = { [P in TNames]: (T & { [name: string]: never })[P]};
type Mutable<T> = MutableHelper<T, keyof T>;
```

Comment: Regarding Typescript playing it safe, here is my mental model: `{readonly theFlag: boolean}` is the set of values that
have `theFlag` with a getter, and `{theFlag: boolean}` is the set of values that have `theFlag` with both a getter and a setter.
Since the latter is a subset of the former, the intersection of them should be the same as `{theFlag: boolean}`.

Comment: According to basic set theory, the intersection of {getter,setter} and {getter} is {getter}.

Comment: @HishamHM Not from my understanding: Imagine a `type T={a:...}` and `U={b:...}`. Each key on the type represents a constraint on `{}`.  `T&U` does not take the intersection of the *keys* (it is not `{}`), it takes the intersection of the *constraints* -- for a type to lie in this intersection, it must be *both* T and U, hence `T&U={a,b}`. This applies to the get/set example -- to be both `{get} & {get, set}` it must contain both the constraint `get` and the constraint `set`: hence `{x} & {readonly x} = {x}`.